# Link CSS Framework in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to link http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css into react-native project.

Is there any way we can use external css frameworks.

Thankyou.

Comment: No, you can't, React Native styling mechanism works totally different, read: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.29/docs/style.html

Answer (score 0):

There is this library that transpiles css/sass to valid react-native styles. https://github.com/sabeurthabti/react-native-css

But I think you would be better off learning flexbox and doing things the react-native way.

Also flexbox is awesome.